# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create new KafkaAdminClient

Tags: java, apache-kafka

while I create topic on mac os the error occur.
when I tried on server where the kafka run the same error occur
with additive error message
`OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: If the number of processors is expected to increase from one, then you should configure the number of parallel GC threads appropriately using -XX:ParallelGCThreads=N`

the command I use is `/opt/homebrew/bin/kafka-topics --create --bootstrap-server ip1:port,ip2:port,ip3:port/test --replication-factor 3 --partitions 1 --topic test`

zookeeper version(linux ec2 t2.micro) : 3.8.1 
kafka version(linux ec2 t2.micro) 3.4.0

local(mac os) kafka version : 3.3.2

If you need more information(zoo.cfg, server.properties etc.), question me

I spend 2 days to find out a solution

full error msg:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create new KafkaAdminClient
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:553)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:485)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.Admin.create(Admin.java:134)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$TopicService$.createAdminClient(TopicCommand.scala:205)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$TopicService$.apply(TopicCommand.scala:209)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:50)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid url in bootstrap.servers: 54.165.35.70:9092/test
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:59)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:48)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:505)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: The quickstart guide, with the correct command syntax, from the Kafka website shouldn't take two days to go over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your topic creation command there is an error on the value of the parameter `--bootstrap-server ip1:port,ip2:port,ip3:port/test`

This parameter should only consist of a comma-separated list of ip:port.

The error comes from the fact that you added /test at the end of this connection string, remove /test to correct your problem

Comment: To clarify, `--zookeeper` can take a chroot, but bootstrap-server cannot